# Match array with mongoose array

Tags: node.js, arrays, backend, mongoose-schema

I am creating a project on node js first time, I have been stuck in a problem that I am passing an array from the client-side(array A) and I have created an array on the backend too(Array b). Now I want to check if "array A" has any other element than "array b" or all the elements of "array a" found in "array b".
FYI, I am using NODE Express and mongoose.
Thanks In Advance

Comment: Do you want to do it on mongodb or in Node.js?

Comment: I am doing it for restriction purpose so yes Node JS

Answer (score 0):

If it is simply comparing 2 arrays, why not something like follows?

```
const arrayA = [1,2,3,4,5];
const arrayB = [1,2,3];

function arrayDifference(baseArray, comparedArray) {
  
  const difference = [];

  for(let element of   comparedArray) {
    if(baseArray.indexOf(element) !== -1) {
      continue;
    }
    difference.push(element);
  }
  return difference;
}

const diffA = arrayDifference(arrayA, arrayB);
console.log(diffA); // []

const diffB = arrayDifference(arrayB, arrayA);
console.log(diffB); // [4, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful, but my purpose for asking that if there is any query for mongoose which done in db because running it in node making server slow